# Reboot of DHCP-Server results in a mess of Client-IP-Addresses

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

in my network at home, driving some ubuntu-pc's one of them is dhcp-server running dhcp3-server. If i reboot this pc all the clients are going offline with a ahavi-ip-address (169.254...). what is going on during the short downtime of the dhcp-server, what is wrong on which side: client or server?

Peace
  Ice

Comment: You need to increase the lease time - at least a day.

Comment: I got it and put on a hiher value. The Question is answered, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [lease time concepts](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DHCPLeaseLifeCycleOverviewAllocationReallocationRe.htm) of DHCP server.

Whenever I restarted the DHCP server, I never expect client to behave nicely.

Comment: Is it a good idea to set the lease time to a very high value, e.g. default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
What do you think?

Comment: I think the best deal would be to keep it a day. By default most DHCP servers are set to 24 hrs IIRC

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution. i wonder why i got a lease-time of 600 in the default configuration...
Now it is fixed, thx.
Ice

Comment: @Ice the default lease time is usually low so configuration errors can be addressed quickly (i.e. if I change the server config, all the clients will update within 10 minutes). You'd typically increase it when you are satisfied with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

well when ever you are running DHCP server you have to disable DHCP in your router. if you do not do this it will overtake your DHCP box. this strange IPs comes form there.

Comment: i do not have a router with a dhcp-service and if it would not set this kind of avahi-ip-addresses (IPv4 uses the special block 169.254.0.0/16 as described in RFC 3927 while IPv6 hosts use the prefix fe80::/10.). 

Have a look at 

[http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Avahi] and

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking]